# Geometric meaning of a conditional trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

The term "conditional trigonometric identity" usually means a statement that "if $A+B+C = \text{half-circle} = 2\pi\text{ radians or }180^\circ$ then a certain equality holds among trigonometric functions of $A,B,C$.

Among well known examples are these:
\begin{align}
\text{If }A+B+C=\text{half-circle, then } & \tan A + \tan B + \tan C = \tan A \tan B \tan C. \\[4pt]
\text{If }A+B+C=\text{half-circle, then } & \sin(2A)+\sin(2B)+\sin(2C) = 4\sin A \sin B \sin C.
\end{align}
For this second one, I know a **geometric interpretation:** these are two different ways of representing the **area** of a triangle inscribed in a circle.  For the first one, I don't know any such interpretation.  But my inquiry here is about another one.  Someone recently posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946524/a-triangle-determinant-that-is-always-zero), asking how to prove that
$$
\text{if }A+B+C=\text{half-circle, then }\det\begin{bmatrix} \sin(2A)& \sin C & \sin B \\ \sin C & \sin(2B) & \sin A\\
\sin B & \sin A & \sin(2C) \end{bmatrix} = 0.
$$
**What is the geometric interpretation of this conditional trigonometric identity?**